# How to set Firefox resource management

Tags: firefox, mjpeg, resource-management

I've got a web application that is spread out over three monitors (three seperate windows that communicate between each other using a broadcast channel). On the screens I show multiple video streams (up to four per screen) in MJPEG format. All video tags consist of standard  tags that get updated from the camera (us usual with IP camera's). I've got a problem with the performance of Firefox. The window that has focus runs fast and shows the streams with 20 fps. However the other two have problems and videos won't run smoothly (about 1 fps). Once I change focus to the other window that window will run smoothly and the other two will drop to 1 fps.

Things get strange when I open a new tab in one of the windows. At that moment ALL windows will run fast and show the video feeds with 20 fps. However after some time the performance issue re-occur. Reopening another tab fixes the problem for some time again.

Does anyone have any idea on how to interfere with the resource managment of Firefox?